# C - 2 2-Dimensional Char Arrays gets Modified

Tags: c, arrays, char, multidimensional-array

I have 2 2d char arrays I use to represent a 5x5 grid. The problem is when it comes to the last 4 line of the function (where I set values of some chars in the array, I use them for testing). Then if i print out the grid it appears like this.

SP_HumanGrid:

```
11---
-----
-----
-----
-----
```

SP_AIGrid:

```
11---
-----
-----
----1
11---
```

Code here:

```
char SP_HumanGrid[4][4]; //The Human player's grid
char SP_AIGrid[4][4]; //The AI player's grid

void SP_EmptyGrids(void)
{
int nRow,nCol;

for (nRow=0;nRow<5;nRow++)
{
    for (nCol=0;nCol<5;nCol++)
    {
        SP_HumanGrid[nRow][nCol] = POINT_WATER;
        SP_AIGrid[nRow][nCol] = POINT_WATER;
    }
}

SP_HumanGrid[0][0] = POINT_SHIP1;
SP_HumanGrid[0][1] = POINT_SHIP1;
SP_AIGrid[0][0] = POINT_SHIP1;
SP_AIGrid[0][1] = POINT_SHIP1;
}
```

I have no other function modifying the values of the SP_AIGrid variable. Shouldn't they look identical, because I set them to the same values?

PS: Don't ask about the idea about this, I'm testing out the language by creating a Battleships game in the console. I know it's err.. stupid but I still wanna try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing **out of bounds**. `SP_AIGrid` or `SP_HumanGrid` are **4x4 matrix**. You are therefore allowed to access from index `0` to `3` not `4`, its an **undefined behaviour**.

You see, you are getting undefined behaviour only on index 4 (both Row & Column) in `SP_AIGrid`. Fortunately, it is not in `SP_HumanGrid`.

Answer (score 3):

Your arrays are to small. You index from zero to four, which is five entries, but you declare them as four only. This means you are overwriting the internal arrays, and writing beyond the bounds of them as well.

The number you put in when declaring an array is not the top index but the size.

Comment: Does that mean I need to declare the arrays as SP_HumanGrid[5]? I thought indices start at 0? Could you please explain because I'm new to this.

Comment: @JohnMarkGabrielCaguicla Yes, I just added that to the answer.

Comment: Sorry I did't see that yet, and Thank you very much! That solved it

Answer (score 1):

Your for loops should be

`for (nRow=0;nRow<4;nRow++)`

and 
`for (nCol=0;nCol<4;nCol++)`

A blind rule to memorise,if you declare an array of size SIZE, your for loop should start with zero and end just 1 before the SIZE. Which means

`for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)`

and in C, do not add `<=` in the comparison.